# Branch coverage% mismatch between Istanbul and Sonar

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, istanbul

My Jenkins job reads lcov file, generated by Istanbul, via Sonar Runner. The numbers/misses in lcov-report generated by Istanbul do not match with that displayed in Sonar. There is 0-7% difference with Istanbul being stricter by finding more misses.

Is it expected? Why the difference?

Environment:

- SonarQube 3.5 and 3.7.4
- SonarRunner 2.3
- Sonar JavaScript plugin 1.6
- Node.js code

Comment: This delta is not expected. Could you provide provide the log of the analysis ? Just in case, do you exclude some file from sonar analysis ?

Comment: @Linda I think it most likely is because ‘sonar.sources’ does not cover all the code.

The problem is that workspace has files and folders that do not belong to the application. Is there a way I can pick and choose files and folders for assigning them to ‘sonar.sources’? In one case, I had only one file in the workspace that belonged to the application, but when I had it as ‘sonar.sources = index.js’, Sonar complained that it is invalid. In most of my cases, source is in ‘lib’ directory and in 1-2 files directly in $WORKSPACE (not in any subfolder, along with other non-source js files).

Answer (score 1):

Coverage% mismatch in a single file shouldn't differ, except for rounding. As for project's %coverage, you'll need to experiment with `sonar.exclusions`. This is what we're using for a specific Node project:

```
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=src/**/*,test/**/*,node_modules/**/*,public/**/*,coverage/**/*,html-report/**/*,views/**/*,Gruntfile.js,*.html
sonar.tests=test
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why we need to specify sonar.exclusions when we have already excluded those files in the Istanbul report? I don't see much point having to have exclusions in 2 places.